# How to register an ItemListener to a CompositeItemProcessor

Tags: java, spring-batch, event-listener, executioncontext

I want to pass some data from one step to another, say from step_1 to step_2. I've passed the data into an ExecutionContext in step_1. In step_2, I'm attempting to recover the data with a @beforeStep that retrieves the JobExecution.

However, step_2 references a CompositeItemProcessor, which does not seem to be registered as a listener by default. How can I register an ItemProcessListener to just one process of the CompositeItemProcessor to recover the JobExecution (to then recover the data from step_1)?

Answer (score 1):

to register any listener  , you can list the listeners in your job - inside the step and then when you implement the listener - you can implement specific listeners

```
  <bean id="customItemProcessListener" 
          class="com.listeners.CustomItemProcessListener" />

     <job id="myJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
        <step id="step2">
            <tasklet>
            <chunk reader="reader" writer="writer"
                commit-interval="1" />
                <listeners>
                <listener ref="customItemProcessListener" />
                </listeners>
            </tasklet>
        </step>
        </job>
```

and then you can implement the processor

```
    public class CustomItemProcessListener implements ItemProcessListener<T> {

    @Override
    public void beforeProcess(T items) {
        System.out.println("ItemProcessListener - beforeProcess");
    }

    @Override
    public void afterProcess(T items , S result) {
        System.out.println("ItemProcessListener - afterProcess");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProcessError(T items , Exception exception) {
        System.out.println("ItemProcessListener - onProcessError ");
    }

}
```